# c binary file greater than source file

Tags: c, gcc, binary

I have a c source file with name simple.c (file size **68 bytes**) and I compiled it using gcc. The output binary file size is **7151 bytes**.

C Source code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 34;
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

I haven't included any header files.

I don't know, how does the C binary file becomes bigger than the source file. Can anyone please explain?

```
test@test-desktop:~/Desktop/c$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 test test 68 Jul 15 15:04 simple.c
test@test-desktop:~/Desktop/c$ gcc simple.c 
test@test-desktop:~/Desktop/c$ ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 test test 7151 Jul 15 15:04 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 test test   68 Jul 15 15:04 simple.c
```

The above is the terminal output.

Comment: In the above question they have #included standard header files. But, i didn't included any header files.

Comment: main is not the first function that is called. The Compiler adds some wrapper around main which then calls main. That wrapper Needs space.

Comment: I will accept your point @WernerHenze. Can you please post a reference link?

Comment: There is no link between source input size and executable output size. Proof #1: remove all optional whitespaces in your source. The executable will be the same size as it is now. Proof #2: add *long* comments between each statement. The executable will be the same size.

Comment: @Valarpirai I don't have a link available, but "crt startup" is a good combination to google, possibly add your specific compiler gcc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a certain one-time overhead even without including anything. There is code running before `main()` (which is setting up `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, [signal handler](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal) tables etc.), and code running after that function returns (e.g. checking for anything registered with [`atexit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) and similar things). This is called the C runtime, traditionally located in [`crt0.o`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0), which is linked into any executable.

Answer (score -1):

It'll be the debug and symbol information. Optimize and strip it:

1. Use `gcc -Os` to optimize for smallest size.
2. Use `strip a.out` to remove the symbols and debug info.

There are also the CRT startup files providing the bulk of your binary that process argc, argv etc and setup your environment. You can opt out of those using `-nostartfiles` but you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Optimizing this code? Seriously? How should that relevantly affect the Output size?

Comment: ...and none of this really answers the question of how the executable could be *larger* than the source.

Comment: @Werner. Review the assembly. Optimization reduces `main` from 10 instructions down to 1 (not including the `ret`).

Comment: ...which *still* doesn't answer why the binary was larger than the source by a comfortable margin. You missed the point of the question.

Comment: OK so I added the real reason for the bulk (CRT startup overhead)